# Constant future warnings with new pyproj

Tags: coordinate-system, geopandas, pyproj

When I work with different CRS in GeoPandas, pyproj module always fires many FutureWarnings.

```
/home/culebron/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyproj/crs.py:77:
FutureWarning: '+init=<authority>:<code>' syntax is deprecated.
'<authority>:<code>' is the preferred initialization method.
```

I see them up to 5 in a row.

Here's a code that causes it:

```
In [1]: crs = 'epsg:3857'
In [2]: import geopandas as gpd
In [3]: df = gpd.read_file('rodovias.gpkg')

In [4]: df.crs
Out[4]: {'init': 'epsg:4326'}

In [5]: df.to_crs(crs)
/home/culebron/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyproj/crs.py:77: FutureWarning: '+init=<authority>:<code>' syntax is deprecated. '<authority>:<code>' is the preferred initialization method.
  return _prepare_from_string(" ".join(pjargs))
Out[5]: 
                     name                                           geometry
0                Arco Sul  MULTILINESTRING ((-5487151.115 -2940693.219, -...
1                   Leste  MULTILINESTRING ((-5482946.592 -2929361.487, -...
```

As you can see, I have no syntax like `'+init=...'` in my code.

Is there a workaround to silence the warnings, or ideally to fix their cause?

(**edit:** and please, don't vote close. I did Google before asking this, and found **absolutely nothing** on topic. Bothering the devs at geopandas github was a bad idea too.)

Comment: Or you can use `df.to_crs(epsg=3857)`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `+init=epsg:xxxx` syntax (or in form of a `{'init': 'epsg:xxx'}`) is being deprecated in PROJ / pyproj (see [here](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/gotchas.html#init-auth-auth-code-should-be-replaced-with-auth-auth-code). You are indeed not using it directly, but, the previous releases of GeoPandas (<= 0.6) were still generating this format under the hood (e.g. when reading files, as you can see from the output of `df.crs`). That is the reason you see this warning.

The latest release of GeoPandas (>= 0.7) has fixed this, and with that version you shouldn't see the warning. With older versions, you can ignore the warning.

See the migration guide for more: https://geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/projections.html#upgrading-to-geopandas-0-7-with-pyproj-2-2-and-proj-6

Comment: oh, that's why I did not find it the issues section :) thanks!

Comment: I'm using geopandas v0.7.0 and I'm seeing this warning

Comment: @AaronBramson if you are not specifying the CRS yourself using the `+init=epsg:xxxx` syntax, and still get the warning, then please open an issue at https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas

Comment: If I follow the conversion guide, I get the error `Cannot transform naive geometries.  Please set a crs on the object first.` when trying to set the crs...Ah ha: the correct syntax in THAT case is `thisData.crs = 'epsg:4326'`